# Remove whitespaces and new lines from XML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Since XML files both for Internet Explorer and Firefox cannot have whites spaces, cause it makes problems for Firefox as it counts white spaces as nodes and Internet Explorer counts comments the same way, I wonder:

How to get rid of white-spaces and new lines from XML file after its being loaded into `xmlDoc` for further processing, so I don't loose the beautiful structure of tabulators and new lines inside of the XML file?

Basically it should do something after that chunk of code:

```
var taby=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TAB");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To remove the white spaces use the following code

```
var str = "<rec> <id> This </id <name> That </name> <type> textbox </type></rec>";
str = str.replace(/>\s*/g, '>');  // Remove space after >
str = str.replace(/\s*</g, '<');  // Remove space before <
```

To remove the new line use the following code

```
var strSingleLineText = strMultiLineText.replace(
    // Replace out the new line character.
    new RegExp( "\\n", "g" ), 
    "" 
    );
```